# Examples of Noetherian Domains of Dimension One

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, noetherian, krull-dimension

I am writing an assignment on Noetherian domains of dimension 1. I have been researching online left and right looking for concrete examples of this domain, but could not find any. I would therefore appreciate you very much if you could help me with links, pointers or outright examples of this domain. I would like examples that are simple, not requiring higher-end tools, befitting the mind of a beginner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every finite ring extension of $\mathbb Z$ is a Noetherian ring of dimension one. For instance, $\mathbb Z[\sqrt{-3}]$ is a Noetherian domain of dimension one (which is not Dedekind).

Answer (score 5):

All Dedekind domains are noetherian domains of dimension $1$. Rings of `algebraic integers`, in arithmetic, are Dedekind domains, some are principal. If they're UFD's they're principal.

Actually, one characterization of Dedekind domains is they're noetherian integrally closed domains of dimension $1$.

Answer (score 3):

If $k$ is a field and $f(X,Y)\in  k[X,Y]\setminus  k$ is an irreducible polynomial, then the quotient ring $A=k[X,Y]/\langle f(X,Y)\rangle$ will be a noetherian  domain of dimension one, not necessarily Dedekind.
  For example if $k=\mathbb Q$ the ring  $A=\mathbb Q[X,Y]/\langle X^n+Y^n-1\rangle$ is a Dedekind domain for all $n\geq 1$, but the one-dimensional noetherian domain $R=\mathbb Q[X,Y]/\langle X^3-Y^2\rangle$ is not Dedekind.

**Geometric interpretation (optional)**
The ring $A$ is the ring of regular functions $A=\mathcal O(V)$ of the affine plane curve $V\subset \mathbb A^2_k \;$ given by the equation $f(x,y)=0$.
The geometric  point of view is very fruitful, for example  if one wants to investigate whether $A$ is Dedekind.

Comment: You are welcome dear A.Magnus !